# Solving $\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{x!}\,\sqrt{x!!}\,\sqrt{x!!!}}}{\sqrt{(x-2)!+x}}=12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{x!}\,\sqrt{x!!}\,\sqrt{x!!!}}}{\sqrt{(x-2)!+x}}=12$$
where $x!!=x(x-2)(x-4)\cdots$ and $x!!!=x(x-3)(x-6)\cdots$ are the [double and triple factorials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html), respectively.

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: What do you mean by the notation "Square = V" ? Is the equation that you're trying to solve:
$$
\frac{x^2! x^2!! x^2 !!! }{((x-2)!+x)^2} = 12
$$
For future reference, please use MathJax to typeset the equations. That way, people will understand what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{\sqrt{x!}\,\sqrt{x!!}\,\sqrt{x!!!}}{\sqrt{(x-2)!+x}}=12$$

Comment: That's right!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your title is quite useless. Next time, try a more descriptive title.

Comment: @JeffersonNascimento: *What's* right? There are two entirely different suggestions above your comment.

Comment: The second option is correct.  The one with square roots

Comment: One Root is missing that covers every numerator above.  Could you please?

Comment: @JeffersonNascimento: Also, to be clear, does "$x!!$" mean "$(x!)!$" (the factorial of the factorial)? or does it mean the [double-factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) (the product of *every other integer*).

Comment: It's a double factorial indeed

Comment: @JeffersonNascimento: So, then "$x!!!$" is the "triple factorial", $x(x-3)(x-6)\cdots$, correct?

Comment: Because, Bro?......

Comment: This looks like an increasing function in $x$, so there will be only one solution. If it cannot be guessed then I doubt this equation can be solved.

Comment: Is there a way to combine these factorials?

Comment: I don't know .... I had never seen this problem

Comment: (x-2)(x-3)...1+x -- denominator

Comment: How to check that $x=2^8\times 3^4$ is a solution or not? Is it possible?

Comment: The answer to the problem is 6

Comment: @JeffersonNascimento: The answer to the problem as written is *not* $6$. You need another square root enclosing the denominator. Should that square root I added to the numerator have enclosed the entire fraction?

Comment: No need! Bro 

Comment: @JeffersonNascimento: Bro, $$6!=720, \qquad 6!!=48, \qquad 6!!! = 18, \qquad (6-2)!+6=4!+6=30$$
Bro, these satisfy
$$\frac{x!\;x!!\;x!!!}{(x-2)!+x}=20736=12^4 \quad\to\quad\frac{\sqrt{x!}\;\sqrt{x!!}\;\sqrt{x!!!}}{\sqrt{(x-2)!+x}}=12^2\quad\to\quad\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x!}\;\sqrt{x!!}\;\sqrt{x!!!}}{\sqrt{(x-2)!+x}}}=12$$ Bro.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion?

Comment: @JeffersonNascimento: You said the answer is $6$. I merely checked, and found that the problem as stated must be incorrect.

Comment: Hmm... Ok......

Comment: Yet, after another update, the expression in post is still wrong.

Comment: Why is the question wrong?

Comment: Read Blue's comments, compare the expressions

Comment: It's been a while since I've been on this issue ...

Comment: @JeffersonNascimento: Please provide the source of this question. This would help clarify things. Plus, it's good to give credit to creators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a particularly-good way to solve this problem except to guess-and-check. That said, there's an observation that helps with the guessing.

Taking the problem statement to be
$$\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x!}\;\sqrt{x!!}\;\sqrt{x!!!}}{\sqrt{(x-2)!+x}}}=12 \tag{$\star$}$$
we can write
$$x!\;x!!\;x!!! = 3^4\cdot 2^8 \cdot (\;(x-2)!+x\;)$$
With the fourth power of $3$ on the right-hand-side, we need at least four $3$s on the left. And we *probably* need at least one $3$ from each factor, from which we suspect that $x$ itself must be a multiple of $3$. Since $x=3$ only gives three $3$s on the left, we try $x=6$: 
$$(6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1)\cdot(6 \cdot 4\cdot 2)\cdot(6 \cdot 3) \;\stackrel{?}{=}\; 3^4 \cdot 2^8 \cdot (\;4!+6) \;=\; 3^4\cdot 2^8 \cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 5 \quad \checkmark$$

This confirms OP's comment that $6$ is in fact the answer (even though this requires re-writing the given equation as $(\star)$).

---

For the problem statement as written (as of this edit)

$$\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{x!}\;\sqrt{x!!}\;\sqrt{x!!!}}}{\sqrt{(x-2)!+x}}=12$$

we'd have

$$x!\;x!!\;x!!! = 3^4\cdot 2^8 \cdot (\;(x-2)!+x\;)^2$$

I'll leave analysis of this version to the reader.

Comment: They sent me the question in a masters group, I don't know where she's from